# How to convert Pascal case into a separate strings?

Tags: python, string

I have a big string in Pascal case and need to make separate strings. How can I do that?

```py
cities = ["KyivKharkivDniproOdessaDonetsk"]
```

end result should be

```py
cities = ["Kyiv", "Kharkiv", "Dnipro", "Odessa", "Donetsk"]
```

Comment: Why is the string like that in the first place? Why do you have a list containing a single string? What have you tried?

Comment: Open letter to students with homework problems: https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems

Answer (score -2, accepted):

That would be as easy as this :

```
import re

cities = ["KyivKharkivDniproOdessaDonetsk"]
split_cities = re.findall(r'[A-Z][^A-Z]*', cities[0])

print(split_cities)
```

In the code above, we use the re.findall() function to match and extract all sequences that start with an uppercase letter ([A-Z]) followed by zero or more non-uppercase letters ([^A-Z]*). This pattern captures each separate city in Pascal case and returns a list of the individual city names.

The result will be `['Kyiv', 'Kharkiv', 'Dnipro', 'Odessa', 'Donetsk']`, as desired.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds How does this look like AI?

Comment: @KellyBundy I tried and got the exact same answer via [ChatGPT](https://i.imgur.com/wfJkCrG.jpg) with a slight modification at the beginning.

Comment: @KellyBundy While it's likely *edited* in this case, there are *at least* four reasons that I suspect that this one was *partially* written by GPT.  I tend to not publicize the methods I use because we have some people who try to evade detection, but with over 1,200 helpful flags on AI-answers, it seems the Moderators (at least when they were allowed to act on them) agreed with my methods ;-)  But as Mario mentioned, yes, plugging this one into ChatGPT and seeing the response(s) was one of the methods I used in this case.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds Ok. Though for completeness: How many declined flags?

Comment: @KellyBundy Fair question - 19 declined flags; 12 (~ 1%) of these were on AI/GPT content.  All of those were in my first month of flagging them here, and in retrospect, they were ones I probably wouldn't flag again.  And for even more completeness, Moderators *do* mark flags as Helpful but decide not to take action - It's rare, and it's tough to get a count of those since they often aren't marked, but I'd estimate another 1% there.  This one would be at the "border" of confidence I'd have in flagging, but I probably *would* be flagging it if the Mods could take action at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like using regex (which is sometimes an useful tool) like one of the previous answers, you could simply do this with `isupper` method and standard beginner-friendly control loops.

```py
cities = "KyivKharkivDniproOdessaDonetsk" 

uppers = []  # list for storing indicies of upper letters

for idx, char in enumerate(cities): #  loop through all characters and their indices
  if char.isupper():
    uppers.append(idx)

cities_split = []  # list for storing final results
for i in range(len(uppers-1)):  # loop through the uppers that we found
  start_idx = uppers[i]  # select the beginning of next city
  if i == len(uppers)-1:  # at the last upper, just take the rest of the string
    cities_split.append(cities[start_idx:])
  else:  # slice what is inbetween two uppers
    end_idx = uppers[i+1]
    cities_split.append(cities[start_idx:end_idx])
```